# Is there a way to list all the objects in a bucket non-recursively in libcloud

Tags: libcloud

I have a basic container that may point to s3 or any other storage service - and I'm trying to list the objects in a certain folder - but I can't find a way to do it non-recursively - all I can do is to pass it a prefix and ex_prefix (which is deprecated) but not a suffix/delimiter/depth - it would always list all the children's objects as well.

Is there a way to pass it a suffix/delimiter/depth?

Comment: I've answered for depth and suffix, by "delimiter" do you mean if it contains a specific character?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Apache libcloud [documentation](https://libcloud.readthedocs.io/en/stable/storage/api.html#libcloud.storage.base.StorageDriver.list_container_objects) there is no way to accomplish that using only libcloud. There is however a pythonic way to do this using list comprehensions. Let's print the entire content of the bucket:

`driver.list_container_objects(bucket)`

We get:

```
    `[<Object: name=A_dirty_chubby_anthropomorphic_badger, size=410938, hash=59643edb7beb48e8904d6557ab4d3d8e, provider=Amazon S3 (eu-central-1) ...>,
<Object: name=A_dirty_chubby_anthropomorphic_badger2, size=379704, hash=6e7f3f1608638be56cecfbd66c1ac902, provider=Amazon S3 (eu-central-1) ...>,
<Object: name=LFS-BOOK-7.9.pdf, size=1736489, hash=e6802cdbec8f4b50d43c3d9cd710bfc2, provider=Amazon S3 (eu-central-1) ...>,
<Object: name=badgers/A_dirty_chubby_anthropomorphic_badger, size=410938, hash=59643edb7beb48e8904d6557ab4d3d8e, provider=Amazon S3 (eu-central-1) ...>,
<Object: name=badgers/A_dirty_chubby_anthropomorphic_badger2, size=379704, hash=6e7f3f1608638be56cecfbd66c1ac902, provider=Amazon S3 (eu-central-1) ...>]`
```

If we want to limit by depth we can do:

`[obj for obj in driver.list_container_objects(bucket) if (obj.name.count('/') < 1)]`

Where we will get:

```
    `[<Object: name=A_dirty_chubby_anthropomorphic_badger, size=410938, hash=59643edb7beb48e8904d6557ab4d3d8e, provider=Amazon S3 (eu-central-1) ...>,
<Object: name=A_dirty_chubby_anthropomorphic_badger2, size=379704, hash=6e7f3f1608638be56cecfbd66c1ac902, provider=Amazon S3 (eu-central-1) ...>,
<Object: name=LFS-BOOK-7.9.pdf, size=1736489, hash=e6802cdbec8f4b50d43c3d9cd710bfc2, provider=Amazon S3 (eu-central-1) ...>]
```

And if we want to filter by suffix we can just do:

`[obj for obj in driver.list_container_objects(bucket) if (obj.name.endswith("badger"))]`

Where we end up getting:

```
    `[<Object: name=A_dirty_chubby_anthropomorphic_badger, size=410938, hash=59643edb7beb48e8904d6557ab4d3d8e, provider=Amazon S3 (eu-central-1) ...>,
<Object: name=badgers/A_dirty_chubby_anthropomorphic_badger, size=410938, hash=59643edb7beb48e8904d6557ab4d3d8e, provider=Amazon S3 (eu-central-1) ...>]`
```